# Tensorflow Saver restores all variables no matter which ones I specified

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to save and restore a subset of variables from Tensorflow graph, so that everything I don't need is discarded and their weights don't take memory. The common advice to pass list or dict of desired variables to `tf.train.Saver` doesn't work: the saver restores all the variables no matter what.

A minimal working example:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    v1 =  tf.get_variable("v1", [5, 5, 3])
    v2 =  tf.get_variable("v2", [5, 5, 3])
    saver = tf.train.Saver([v2])
    initializer2 = tf.variables_initializer([v1, v2])
    sess.run(initializer2)
saver.save(sess, '/path/to/tf_model')

sess2 = tf.Session()
checkpoint = '/path/to/tf_model.meta'
saver.restore(sess2, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(checkpoint)))

with sess2.as_default(), sess2.graph.as_default():
    loaded_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

print(loaded_vars)
```

outputs

```
[<tf.Variable 'v1:0' shape=(5, 5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'v2:0' shape=(5, 5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Nevertheless, `print(saver._var_list)` outputs

`[<tf.Variable 'v2:0' shape=(5, 5, 3) dtype=float32_ref>]`

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do. Please examine the code carefully.

#### To save the selected variables

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

# =============================================================================
# to save
# =============================================================================

# create variables
v1 =  tf.get_variable(name="v1", initializer=[5, 5, 3])
v2 =  tf.get_variable(name="v2", initializer=[5, 5, 3])

# initialize variables
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# ops to save variable v2
saver = tf.train.Saver({"my_v2": v2})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, './tf_vars/model.ckpt')
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

'Output':
Model saved in file: ./tf_vars/model.ckpt
```

#### To restore the saved variables

```
# =============================================================================
# to restore
# =============================================================================

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0, 0, 0], name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0, 0, 0], name="v2")

# initialize variables
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#  ops to restore variable v2.
saver = tf.train.Saver({"my_v2": v2})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, './tf_vars/model.ckpt')
    print("v1: %s" % v1.eval())
    print("v2: %s" % v2.eval())

    print("V2 variable restored.")

'Output':
v1: [0 0 0]
v2: [5 5 3]
V2 variable restored.
```

Comment: Thank you! As I understand, the difference is that I need first to define and initialize variables once again, and then restore only weights from .ckpt file, rather than the graph from .meta. For some reason I though that .ckpt is deprecated format...

Comment: Ekaba is correct. Also, it is not needed to initialize all the variables (tf.global_variable) if you know what variables to initialize. I added a piece of code in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The tf.trainable_variables() return list of variable objects stored in a graph. By default over here both your variables v1 and v2 will be stored in the graph. When you use `saver = tf.train.Saver([v2])`, you are only saving the variable v2 and you are not saving any value for v1. But still, the variable v1 exists in your graph.  This is the reason why we could see all the variable when you `print(loaded_vars)`. You could actually check whether a variable has a value(initialized) or not using this piece of code

```
uninitialized_vars = []
for var in tf.all_variables():
    try:
        sess.run(var)
    except tf.errors.FailedPreconditionError:
        uninitialized_vars.append(var)

print(uninitialized_vars)
```

Hope this helps!

Also, it is not needed to initialize all the variables (tf.global_variable) if you know what variables to initialize.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

# Add ops to save and restore only `v2` using the name "v2"
saver = tf.train.Saver({"v2": v2})

# Use the saver object normally after that.
with tf.Session() as sess:
# Initialize v1 since the saver will not.
v1.initializer.run()
saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

Comment: I modified the question, now I initialize both the variables before storing. The result remains the same, and now `uninitialized_vars` is empty list.